# How to do an HTTP Post in Android to web api

Tags: java, android, url, asp.net-web-api, httpurlconnection

I am trying to do a post to web api from android. The below is the code that I am using in android. The code is running without exception however the data is not inserted to the database. I included the code that I am using.

```
@Override
protected List doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
    List userDetails3 = new ArrayList();
    URL url = null;
    String urlshared = "http://10.0.0.9/MyWebApi/api/Student/PostAddStudent?userName="+"s4"+"&"+"password="+"1234"+"&"+"firsName="+"z"+"&"+"lastName="+"g"+"&"+"telephone="+"9160000000"+"&"+"address="+"2300 xxx"+"&"+"aliasMailId="+"s1.xx"+"&"+"emailId="+"xx@gmail.com"+"&"+"skypeId="+"z.g"+"";

    try {
            url = new URL(urlshared);
        }
    catch (MalformedURLException exception) 
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        try 
        {
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream()); // this code is executed without exception
        } 
        catch (IOException exception) 
        {
            exception.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        return userDetails3; // (in debug) the code will run successfuly till here without exception 
}
```

I am trying to access the PostAddStudent in the webapi. The below is my implementation of the controller and I excluded the codes inside the methods. For your information, I did test "PostAddStudent" and the other methods in the RegisterController by using the postman and they are working fine and the data inserted to database.

```
public class RegisterController : ApiController
{      
    public IEnumerable<Register> GetRegisterAuth(string userName,string password)
    {
        //return instance of register
    }

    public IEnumerable<Register> GetRegisterByUserName(string userName)
    {
        //return instance of register
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PostAddInstructor(string instUserName, string instPassword, string instFirsName, string instLastName, string instTelephone, string instAddress, string instAliasMailId, string instEmailId, string instSkypeId)
    {
         //add to database and if okay will return System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created       
         var response = Request.CreateResponse<Instructor>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, inst);
         //if error exist then just return Badrequest
         var response = Request.CreateResponse<Instructor>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, inst);            
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PostAddStudent(string userName, string password, string firsName, string lastName, string telephone, string address, string aliasMailId, string emailId, string skypeId)
    {
         //add to database and if okay will return System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created       
         var response = Request.CreateResponse<Instructor>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, inst);
         //if error exist then just return Badrequest
         var response = Request.CreateResponse<Instructor>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, inst);            
    }   
}
```

the below is the RouteConfig

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

the below is the WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I need the android code that can do the post to PostAddStudent.

thanks

Comment: I suggest you use volley... ;) ezlife

Comment: All URL parameters need to be urlencoded. You use Smartphone ore emulator for tests?

Comment: I use smartPhone for test.

Comment: follow this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download, maybe you need `httpURLConnection.connect()` after `setRequestMethod`

Comment: If you put all parameters in the url you make a GET request. So then you don't need to POST also. Find out first what kind of method the web api expects.

Comment: `by using the postman`. Please explain exactly what yoy did.

Comment: In postman I put the link to "http://localhost:62710/api/Register/PostAddStudent/" then I changed the request to "POST". after that I added the parameters from "Params". I did not include anything in the body. Then I clicked on "Send", the response returned and I checked my database where I found new record inserted successful.

Comment: in this link developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/…, shall I do a "GET" or "POST" while using conn.setRequestMethod("GET").

Comment: Check if you have connection from your smartphone to server (10.0.0.9)

Comment: There is a connection since I am able to do Get requests to the same web api server successfully.

Comment: You should start to remove the parameters from the used url. Then construct name value pairs out of them. Use those as post body. I wonder why you have to ask how you should post some parameters with their values as there are hundreds examples of how to do that on this site. Every day you can see them. Just read a couple of android tagged pages and you will find in no time.

Comment: I did follow the code in this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download and it did throw exception. I also checked when the setRequestMethod is equal to "Get" and "Post. also I put the httpURLConnection.connect() after and before setRequestMethod without success.

Comment: greenapps, I did follow an example which use the value pairs as will and did not work. Then I went to find an examples which included the parameters in the url.

Comment: `after that I added the parameters from "Params". I did not include anything in the body.` ??? How should that work? Those params should be the body of your post request. Unclear why there are params and a body. There should only be a body consisting out of parameters.

Comment: Post your code using the name value pairs. Only then we can help.

Comment: Yes, in postman I included the parameters from the "Params" and the request is "Post". I just used the poastman again and I used the .net web api to debug and it accessed the PostAddStudent and sent the parameters to it successfully.

Comment: I will add a code which use the value pair However do I need to edit the PostAddStudent in the web api? or it is okay.

Comment: `do I need to edit the PostAddStuden` ???? Why are you asking???? You said that it worked! So everyone now assumes that your Android code needs to be adapted. By the way: in your former comment you did not use the word body. So for me it was a useless answer as i informed about the body.